# SQLAlchemy ORM update tries to update an unspecified column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

i have a problem when updating a model

this is my route:

```
@router.put('/{id}/update-status')
async def update_project_status(id: UUID, status: int , user = Depends(current_active_user)):
    try:
        session = async_session_maker()
        query = select(Project).where(Project.id == id)
        result = await session.scalars(query)
        project = result.one()
        project.project_status_id = status
        await session.commit()
        await session.close()
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        return repr(error)
```

Project model:

```
class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'
    id= Column(GUID, primary_key=True)
    name= Column(String(length=320))
    desc= Column(String(length=320))
    dimensions= Column(JSON)
    images_format= Column(String(length=10), default="PNG")
    config= Column(JSON, nullable=True)
    contract_address= Column(String(length=64), nullable=True)
    created_at= Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    user_id= Column(GUID, ForeignKey('users.id'), onupdate='CASCADE')
    user= relationship("UserTable", back_populates="projects", lazy='subquery')
    smart_contract_id= Column(Integer, ForeignKey('smart_contracts.id'), nullable=True)
    smart_contract= relationship("SmartContract", back_populates="projects")
    project_status_id= Column(Integer, ForeignKey('project_status.id'), nullable=True)
    project_status= relationship("ProjectStatus", back_populates="project")
```

and this is the error:

```
(builtins.ValueError) badly formed hexadecimal UUID string
[SQL: UPDATE projects SET user_id=%s, project_status_id=%s WHERE projects.id = %s]
[parameters: [{'project_status_id': 2, 'projects_id': UUID('ed2feea0-3f7f-464c-9055-e98db87a9d44')}]]
```

from what i see the update query also tries to change the user_id column, but in the code i don't specify this thing anywhere.
Hope you can help me!!

Comment: `update_project_status` specifies `user = Depends(current_active_user)` but then it doesn't seem to reference `user` anywhere else. If you omit that dependency does it change the behaviour?

Comment: @GordThompson i tried but it doesn't change. I need that dependency for the logged user

Comment: Immediately before you `.commit()`, print or log `f"user_id status: {'unmodified' if 'user_id' in project._sa_instance_state.unmodified else 'modified'}"` . If it shows as "modified" then something in your code is causing SQLAlchemy to believe that it needs to write that value back to the database.